# Get all entries without a specific value in One to Many relationship SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause, sql-in, sql-except

I have a Exercise table, and a Tag table. Each exercise can have several tags so I have a third table for the one to many relationship.

What I try to achieve is getting all the exercises that does NOT have a specific tag.

Data example:

```
Exercise 1
Exercise 2
Exercise 3

Tag 1
Tag 2

Exercise 1 - Tag 1
Exercise 1 - Tag 2
Exercise 2 - Tag 1
Exercise 3 - Tag 2
```

In this case, looking for exercises not having tag 1, I should get Exercise 3 only.

Last attempt I have is:

```
SELECT Exercise.id FROM Exercise, Tags 
INNER JOIN TagsExercises 
ON Exercise.id=TagsExercises.idExercise AND TagsExercises.idTag=Tags.id 
WHERE Tags.id NOT in ( '3' )
GROUP BY Exercise.id;
```

And I get Exercise 3 AND Exercise 1 because of the entry with tag 2... u.u
Not sure how to form the SQL, any ideas?

Comment: You're looking for that don't have the number '1' in the whole record?

Comment: "In this case, looking for exercises not having tag 1, I should get Exercise 3 only."  Exercise 1 has a Tag 2 therefore 1 AND 3 should be returned. What exactly are you trying to filter on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all the `id`s of the table `Exercise` except the ones that have a tag '1':

```
SELECT id FROM Exercise
EXCEPT
SELECT idExercise FROM TagsExercises WHERE idTag = '1';
```

Use the operator `IN` only if you want to include more than one tags.

Or:

```
SELECT id 
FROM Exercise
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT idExercise FROM TagsExercises WHERE idTag = '1');
```

Comment: Nice! that was perfect :D